# Cant get answer printed from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

So im doing this as a some sort of practice and i cant really figure out whats wrong with my code, also i have a question about something that i would also like to do.

So heres the first part, this is called index.php and its basically the main page.

```js
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("buttonV").addEventListener('click',function(){showUser(1,'button_values')});
        document.getElementById("buttonD").addEventListener('click',function(){showUser(2,'select_values')});
        var year=document.getElementById("year").innerHTML;
        var month=document.getElementById("month").innerHTML;
        var day=document.getElementById("day").innerHTML;
        console.log("year");


        function showUser(sql,div)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML='<img src="ajax_loader.gif" />';
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","get_ajax.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send("sql="+sql);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form>
    <input id="buttonV" type="button" value="View Log">
</form>
</div>

<div>
<form>
    Day:
    <select name="day" id="day">
        <?PHP for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
    Month:
    <select name="month" id="month">
        <?PHP for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
    Year:
    <select name="year" id="year">
        <?PHP for($i=1980; $i<=2016; $i++)
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="see users by datetime" id="buttonD">
</form>
<br />
</div>
<div id="button_values"></div><br />
<div id="select_values"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What im supposed to have here is a button which will show all of the data from the table log in my database called wp3_ajax. Also in my db i have an another table called users, from where im supposed to replace the row user_id from the log table with the username from the users table. Basically, the buttons supposed to show me the username, browser, ip and datetime. All of it needs to get printed out on the same page using ajax.

So heres the second part of the code which is in get_ajax.php.

```js
<?php

//$date=$_GET["date"];

include ("db_config.php");
include ("config.php");

$sql="";


$sqls[1]="SELECT l.ip,l.browser,l.datetime,u.username FROM `log` as l,user as u WHERE u.user_id=l.user_id ORDER BY l.datetime DESC";
//$sqls[2]="SELECT * FROM  'log' WHERE date('datetime')='$date'";
if(isset($_GET['sql']))
{
$sql=(int)mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['sql']);
if(($sql>=1 OR $sql<=2))
{
$result= mysqli_query($connection,$sqls[$sql]) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo "$record[username]. $record[browser], $record[ip], $record[datetime] <br />";
}
    }
        }
else
echo "No access!!";
}
else
echo "No access!";
?>
```

For some reason i cant get the button on the main page to do anything. I cant figure out whats the problem.

Also one more thing that i would like to do is have 3 select options as seen above, which when you select a date display the log of the user who has signed on on the choosen date.But i have to cut off the time from datetime and make it just a date. I hope you can understand what i mean by that (sorry english isnt my first language), if you dont feel free to ask me to clarify.

Im also going to include all of these files in a zip which ill upload here:[on file dropper](http://www.filedropper.com/ajax_7)

Since i also have a db_config.php and a config.php which contains salted tokens,i also inculded my sql file. But that part with tokens isnt that important, i just want to see why my button isnt displaying anything and how would i go about displaying logs by a specific date.

I would really appreciate the help, and would also like to thank you in advance if you decide to help me.

Comment: Don't you need to remove the double quotes? `document.getElementById("div")`

Comment: There is no element with an ID of "div", and `getElementById(div)` will throw "div is undefined". Are you supporting IE5?? Why don't you just use jQuery and do `$("#someDiv").load('someUrl.php')` ?

Comment: Your js code is executing before your elements are created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you get the users with this date and time using button "See Users By Datetime"

still I am calling a function from the button like

```
<input type="button" value="see users by datetime" onclick="setDetails()">

<script>
    function setDetails()
    {
       //Remove details from the starting of script and added into this function as below

       document.getElementById("buttonV").addEventListener('click',function(){showUser(1,'button_values')});
       document.getElementById("buttonD").addEventListener('click',function(){showUser(2,'select_values')});
       var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
       var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
       var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
       console.log("dd/mm/yyyy : "+day +"/"+ month +"/"+year);
    }
</script>
```

Then call the function **showUser(sql,div)** using two different buttons for displaying value in different div like

```
<input id="buttonV" type="button" value="View Log by Button V">
<input id="buttonD" type="button" value="View Log by Button D">
```

Try implementing this to your page and let me know what output you getting by this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!! It did help and ive noticed some dumb mistakes. So , now i made some alterations and the button to show log files works! I also edited the code to choose a date, but for some reason it just gets stuck on ajax's loading gif. Ill post what i altered here: [link](http://pastebin.com/k9BEg8wc) also thanks to the other people who answered!

Comment: Also, sorry for making an another comment. Ive tried implementing your code with the function but for some reason it didnt work very well. It might just be that i didnt put it in the right places. Another thing, which im not sure is a mistake but, when i console log my date values it just returns the default ones. Does that change dynamically when i send it with ajax? Thanks once again, i appreciate the help.

Comment: I have uploaded your index.php file onto [this link](http://pastebin.com/VDESxGCd) with changes what i have made so please have a look, update your index.php file and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve it with just the one function, but i wasnt sending the date variable right and i had some unnecessary lines in my get _ajax code. Thanks once again!